# Jacoco IT report created, but no html

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I have a multi module java maven project, with one of the modules containing integration tests. I used the jacoco-maven-plugin and successfully generated the jacoco-it.exec in that module. But for some reason the html report is not created. Also sonar does not read this report.

It works fine for unit tests, but not for the integration tests.

Here is what I added to the pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                            <element>BUNDLE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                    <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.1</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>target/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                    <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report-integration</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report-integration</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>${failsafe.argLine}</argLine>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>verify</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a HTML report of the integration tests you will have to use the maven-failsafe-report-plugin. But I believe this shows a report of all tests, both unit and integration

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/